# Possible conflict with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have integrated a plugin called colorbox. This i believe is a jquery plug-in which allows users to open an image ontop of the existing page in a gallery format.

I have successfully integrated this plug-in on this page here (just under first img)...

http://www.transformyourshape.co.uk/Herbalife-Weight-Gain.php

Now i have tried to replicate this again on this web page but it loads in a completely new page, this file shares the same folder as the one above so i am 100% sure that all file locations are accurate in the scripts.

http://www.transformyourshape.co.uk/Herbalife-H24-Sport.php

Somewhere i believe is a conflict with jquery but i cannot find it for the life of me, i would appreciate any help with this issue regardless to how small the help or advice is.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your jquery cannot be found: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: thank you for clarifying. This is the code i am using to define where the script is <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/js/contactForm/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> this is defiantly the correct location so i was wondering how to correct this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be loading in the colorbox plugin before the actual jQuery library.

You need to load in the jQuery library before any plugins.

Comment: Thnak you for that obvious spot :/ I spent so long looking for code errors i completely forgot to even check that I used the correct editable head region to apply the code after loading jquery. Works perfectly now. Many Many Thanks